# Write to Mongodb from Apache storm

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, apache-storm

I am trying to write a custom stream grouping which writes to Mongodb. I am running a local cluster for now. I have a custom stream class and a mongo object. I write to mongodb in both the prepare() and chooseTask(). It writes to mongodb but the supervisors cannot start. I see this error in the supervisor log:

```
b.s.d.worker [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient

at storm.starter.MongoMonitorObject.<init>(MongoMonitorObject.java:23) ~[stormjar.jar:0.10.0]


at storm.starter.ModStreamGrouping.prepare(ModStreamGrouping.java:94)
 ~[stormjar.jar:0.10.0]
```

I am making changes in the storm starter project for now.

```
public class ModStreamGrouping implements CustomStreamGrouping, Serializable{

  java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> targetTasks = new ArrayList();

  @Override
  public List<Integer> chooseTasks(int taskId,List<Object> values) {
      System.out.println("taskiD = " + taskId);
      System.out.println("values = " + values);
      return numTasks[0];
  }

  @Override
  public void prepare(WorkerTopologyContext context, GlobalStreamId stream, java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> targetTasks) {

      MongoMonitorObject mmo = new 
      System.out.println(" in prep() ");
      System.out.println("targetTasks = " + targetTasks);
      numTasks = targetTasks.size();

  }
}

public class MongoMonitorObject {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoMonitorObject.class);

  public MongoMonitorObject(java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> targetTasks){
  try{
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "loadDB" );
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("testCollection");
    for (Integer task : targetTasks) {
       BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
       document.put("tid", task);
       collection.insert(document);
    }
  }

  catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.out.println(" in UnknownHostException ");
    LOG.info(" in UnknownHostException ");
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(" in Exception ");
    LOG.info(" in Exception ");
  }
  }
}
```

The stream grouping is defined in a ModStreamGrouping.java and mongo connection is defined in MongoMonitorObject.java. Both belong to the package storm.starter.

I can upload the topology but the supervisors cannot spawn workers. There's a small link I'm missing somewhere but I don't know where exactly. I added the following in storm starter's pom.xml to include mongodb connectivity:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I assume it is related to the scope of the dependencies I've added in the pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
I read it here:  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver

mongodb-java-driver is a all-in-one jar, it contains bson and core

Therefore dependency `mongodb-java-driver` is enough.

If use dependency `mongodb-driver` , dependencies `bson` and `core` are needed.

**Original post:**

Try add `mongodb-driver-core` and use the newer version dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The MongoDB Java Driver uber-artifact, containing mongodb-driver, mongodb-driver-core, and bson

Check it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver)

Comment: After including it, it doesn't compile at all. Shows error on all the objects of Mongodb.

Comment: It doesn't work, I've tried. With the dependencies I've mentioned, the build succeeds, but the workers failed to be spawned. With this dependency, the build fails.

Comment: @mini.1601  what is your mongodb database version?  mongo-java-driver 2.13 is not compatible with MongoDB 3.2  reference here:https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-mongodb-java

Comment: I have 3.2.4. I included: mongo-driver dependency this time but still the worker has not spawned. The database is updated, but the supervisor log still has error.

Comment: Found the solution. Thanks @haifzhan. Include the following in the pom.xml : <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @mini.1601 it is in my last comment. 2.13 is not compatible with MongoDB3.2.  glad to hear you solved the problem:)